# Jagged Array in Excel VBA, Type Mismatch Error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to create a jagged array with an array of Double() arrays.  I am simply trying to add this a() Double into d() dynamically.  The error comes when I try to pull one of the copies of a from d, and put it into x.

```
Sub Test3()
 Dim a() As Double, i As Integer
 ReDim a(1 To 10, 1 To 3)
 a(1, 2) = 3.5

 Dim d() As Variant

 For i = 1 To 3
  ReDim Preserve d(1 To i)
  d(i) = Array(a)
 Next i


 Dim x() As Double
 x = d(1)   ' Error, Type Mismatch

 MsgBox (x(1, 2))

End Sub
```

Comment: It is working now when I ReDim x(1 to 10, 1 to 3).  Or when I used the size of d(1).  Is there a way to do it without sizing x first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Change Array(a) to a.

```
Sub Test3()
 Dim a() As Double, i As Integer
 ReDim a(1 To 10, 1 To 3)
 a(1, 2) = 3.5

 Dim d() As Variant

 For i = 1 To 3
  ReDim Preserve d(1 To i)
  d(i) = a
 Next i


 Dim x() As Double
 x = d(1)   ' Error, Type Mismatch

 MsgBox (x(1, 2))

End Sub
```